# img visible but disabled

Tags: html, css, animation, hover

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="mitcsinaltunk" style="position:absolute;left:5px;top:3px;text-align: left">
    <div class="triangle"><img src="images/triangle.png"></div>
    <img id="kep1" src="mitcsinaltunk/img1_s.jpg"  class="mitcsinaltunk">
</div>
```

on `#kep1.hover()` starts an animation and fadeIn triangle.png. triangle.png is on `#kep1`. When I take the mouse on triangle.png, stops `#kep1.hover()` animation.

Can I make triangle visible, but disabled?

Comment: You mean the animation will be disabled, right? Not the triangle.

Answer (score 0):

Try binding your `.hover()` event to the `.mitcsinaltunk` container instead. Your question is a little hard to understand (please post your JS), but my guess is that when the mouse hovers over triangle.png, mouse focus on the original image is lost, stopping the fade in animation. Binding to the containing element will solve this.